# 500 Internal Server Error with nginx local host

Tags: linux, nginx, php, localhost

I am using Linux Mint 17. I am trying to setup PHP 7.1 or PHP 7.2 with nginx but whenever I access a php script I get `500 Internal Server Error`. Whenever I restart nginx or PHP, I receive no errors.

Here are the contents of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I urgently need to get this working.

### Edit

I fixed the 500 Error by adding `worker_rlimit_nofile 100048` and changing  `worker_connections` to `100048`. Unfortunately, now it says "An error occurred" and the logs show:

```
2018/02/11 21:53:23 [crit] 13219#13219: *1012 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (24: Too many open files), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/info.php", host: "127.0.0.1"
2018/02/11 21:53:48 [crit] 13263#13263: *56464 connect() to 127.0.0.1:80 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/info.php", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: nginx is listening on port 80, but is also being configured to use port 80 as an upstream (under the "proxy php scripts to apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80"). try getting rid of that location block.

Comment: It looks like nginx is proxying back to itself, not to Apache.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not trying to proxy to apache. I want nginx to handle the php. The problem is, I've never used nginx before and I urgently need to get this to work.

Comment: Then you should change or remove that section.

Comment: @JonahB I commented that code out and it solved the error. Unfortunately, I now get a different error, `*1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"`. The file `php7.2-fpm.sock` appears to have disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it does have nothing to do with the `worker` settings you mentioned.

Also having two locations `location ~ \.php$ {` does not make sense. I read from your comments that you've alradey removed the first one:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

Good.

Now find out why PHP-fpm is not working:

- Is PHP-fpm installed and running? Check with `service php7.2-fpm status`
- Where has the socket file gone? Check settings in your socket config file here `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/`
- Check if PHP-fpm uses the correct user with permissions for the application folders.

Other nginx config issues:

- Add `try_files`:

  ```
  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  ```
- remove the `root           html;` line from your `location ~ \.php$ {`section.
- Don't put these two lines in a `location` section. Just add them without `location / { }` around:

  ```
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  ```

Comment: I got it working. I had to repeatedly check out the log files to fix the problem. There was a problem with `fastcgi_param`. The default line, '#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;` is completely wrong. There was also a permissions problem with the `sock` file that I fixed with `sudo chmod 777 /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working! :-) Yes, that fastcgi_param line should probably be `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`. I did not mention that as it was commended out `#`already in your config. Your sudo chmod 777 is only a temporary solution and might break on further config changes or restarts. I suggest setting the correct permissions permanently in the according pool config file here `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/`.